# Android Convert Central Time to Local Time

Tags: java, android, timezone, timestamp

I have a MySql database that stores a timestamp for each record I insert.  I pull that timestamp into my Android application as a string.  My database is located on a server that has a TimeZone of CST.  I want to convert that CST timestamp to the Android device's local time.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Local time off the cell-tower or local time set by the user? Not sure user's still set their own time zone, but which did you have in mind?

Comment: If there phone time says 10:18AM, I want to grab whatever timezone there phone is representing and convert the time with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't you simply convert the date with [simpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)? 
then you just define the structure of your incoming date like that (df) and transform it to the form you want (df):

```
private static DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
private static DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy 'at' HH:mm");

public void setyourDate(String yourDate) {
Date date2;
yourDate = getyourDate() + "" + yourDate;
try {
date2 = df.parse(yourDate);
yourDate = df2.format(date2);

} catch (ParseException e) {
}
this.yourDate = yourDate;
}
```

does it make sense?

Comment: I think this will work nicely when I want to show the timestamp in a different format.  I am looking to convert my timestamp from a CST timezone to the users local timezone.

Answer (score 7):

Use `getTimeZone.getDefault` combined with according to the [Android documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html)

> public static synchronized TimeZone
>   getDefault ()
>
> Gets the default time zone. Returns
>   the default time zone.

So since you know that CST is -6:00 from GMT, and you get a local timezone saying the user is +9:00 (Japan), you'd know to adjust your MySQL DB times by +15 hours (9 - (-6)). Or if they are in Miami (EST, -5), you would adjust by adding one hour (-5 - (-6)). If the are in Portland, Oregon, (PST -8), you would subtract 2 hours (-8 -(-6)).

So really you just need to get the local timezone offset and feed it into the basic equation:  `TimeZone.getDefault + 6` and you'll know what to add or subtract to your local DB. (+6 since -(-6) always works out to +6).

If I knew the first thing about writing Java, I'd go the extra step and write a bit of sample code, but alas, I'm only smart enough for scripts.

### Crude Attempt at Java

I already said I have no idea how to do Java or object oriented anything, right?

Here's a crude attempt from just poking around the Android documentation. Any fine points or simple "Not even close" remarks welcome. Bear in mind that I figured out the right method and class already just from a quick search and I came up with a simple equation for converting the timezone offset for anywhere to CST, so I'm not a dunce, just someone who doesn't know when to leave well enough alone. Anyway, crude attempt:

```
System now = System.currentTimeMillis (); //Gets current local time in ms
TimeZone local_tz = TimeZone.getDefault();  //Gets current local TZ of phone
tz_offset_gmt = local_tz.getOffset(now)/3600000; // Get Offset in ms, divide by 3600000
tz_offset_cst = tz_offset_gmt + 6;  // add offset to 6 to get current TZ offset to CST.
```

Anywhere close to how to do this in java?

Comment: Perfect perfect!  This makes sense.  I thought maybe there was a function that would automagically do ti for me. You and @Sephy have been most helpful!

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have a string of date in CST, parse it with timezone CST and then format it with the default timezone on your android.

```
String s = "2011-01-01 12:00:00";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"));
Date timestamp = null;
try {
    timestamp = df.parse(s);
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    System.out.println(df.format(timestamp));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I want to write my answer. Assume, the timestamp you get from SQL is like the following format: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss

```
public static Date convertStringToDate(String strDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"));
    return sdf.parse(strDate);
}
```