# Converting a date string from a timezone to different time zone

Tags: java, android, calendar

I have a date that I get from a server formatted in EST like this

`05/07/2012 16:55:55` goes month/day/year then time

if the phone is not in EST how can I convert it to the timezone the phone is in?

it would be not problem if I got the time in milliseconds but I dont

**EDIT:**

ok now the time is not correct when formatting

```
                String sTOC = oNewSTMsg.getAttribute("TOC").toString();
                String timezoneID = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
                DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss");
                format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
                String newtimezoneID = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
                Date timestamp = null;
                try{
                    timestamp = format.parse(sTOC);
                    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                    timezoneID = format.format(timestamp);
                }catch(ParseException e){

                }
```

I convert it to "EST" then format that time to the default `TimeZone` but the time is always off by an hour, not sure why?

Comment: can you convert source date/time (in EST) into UTC? You can detect phone's timezone settings and convert the source UTC datetime into local datetime based on phone timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to get a UNIX timestamp:

```
String serverResp = "05/07/2012 16:55:55";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse(serverResp);
```

Now you have the timestamp, which you know how to use.

Here's another question which covers conversion, in case you are curious: [Android Convert Central Time to Local Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407719/android-convert-central-time-to-local-time)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DateFormat` class to parse the String into a `Date`. See the introduction to the API document here... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

You can then create a Calendar for the Date...

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance().setTime(date);
```

And then you can change the timezone on the Calendar to a different timezone using `setTimezone()`. Or just get the time in milliseconds, using `getTimeInMillis()`

Using the `Calendar`, `Date`, and `DateFormat` classes should put you in the right direction.

See the `Calendar` documentation here... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html